# Passing Objects from Java(BlazeDs) Server to Front end Flex app

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, flex4, flexbuilder, blazeds

I am looking for some help. I have set up a Java Dynamic web project which uses BlazeDs. This is on a Tomcat server and can send and recieve strings to a front end Flex project.

My question is now that the AMF channels are set up to communicate how can I pass Objects such as ArrayLists or Two Dimensional arrays accross the channel and render them in the flex app (Say through a datagrid?) Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mechanism to send Objects is the same as with Strings. Instead of a service returning or receiving a String it can return or receive an Object, a List, etc.

What you need to keep in mind is how data is serialized/de-serialized, this is, how data is converted from an ActionScript data type to a Java data type and viceversa. This link can help
[link text](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=serialize_data_1.html)

Comment: Thanks Javier. This is of great help.

I think I overcomplicated it too begin with! I wish there was more documentation on java - flex remoting about. 

Since I've started to learn flex ive felt like ive been pulling teeth trying to find the answers!

If you know of anymore good sources please keep me posted and thanks again

Comment: Take a look on Coenraets (http://coenraets.org) blog, you will find plenty of them.